# Story where child is raised by robots and 'rescued' by humans

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember what book this was. Think it was a scene in a full length novel. Might have been adult sci-fi or young adult. The bits I remember clearly:

- There was an 'orphanage' where children were raised by robots without human contact
- The main character (almost certain it was a female human) attacks the orphanage at some point and rescues the children or one particular child
- The child was scared of the humans because it had only ever had robot contact
- After they attacked the orphanage there was a battle

I can't quite remember!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Search_for_WondLa

Comment: @Richard Wow good pick it ticks the boxes... But unfortunately not the one I was thinking of, I've not read that.

Comment: I didn't think it was the right one, hence why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: Reminds me of the scenes on Solaria with the Solarian child Fallom from Asimov's [*Foundation and Earth*](http://www.amazon.com/Foundation-Earth-Isaac-Asimov-ebook/dp/B003EY7IHM) .

Comment: @JoeL. Yes it is similar! I actually recently read that as was re-reading the foundation books, I think that was what reminded me of this other story. I've started on Asimov's Robot books now and it's possible it's in one of them. But in the one I remember the child was a toddler, whereas Fallom was older. And the battle afterwards was more intense. Also I think there may have been several children in the one I'm asking about.

Comment: Very similar to P.K. Dick short story "Progeny" : https://philipkdickreview.wordpress.com/2014/05/10/progeny/, but no battles in this one.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly EG Von Wald's *Hemeac*.

If it is, at the end the rescuers look glumly at the children and say "What do we do with them? They're nothing but living robots" and Hemeac feels a warm glow of pride at the compliment.

Answer (score -1):

Could this be *The Wrong Unit* by Rob Dircks?

[https://www.amazon.com/Wrong-Unit-Novel-Rob-Dircks-ebook/dp/B01HWQ1ONG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HWQ1ONG)

Comment: Could you state in your answer the reasons you believe this might be the book in question?

Comment: Given this novel wasn't released until 2016, a year after the question was posed, this seems unlikely.